# In Sikuli, How to find and click a minimum of 3 identical images?

Tags: python, automation, jython, sikuli

I'm trying to click no less than 3 of the same image, but with `findAll()` I am having difficulty with sikuli wanting to select only 1 image when I don't want it to select any if there is not 3 or more.

```
if exists(Pattern("1474201252795.png").similar(0.95)):
    wait(1)
    for x in findAll(Pattern("1474201252795.png").similar(0.95)):
        click(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just count the images first and check if the count is higher than 3.

```
imageCount=0

images = []

# find all images and store them in a list to prevent additional search
for image in findAll("Win7StartBtn.png"):
    images.append(image)

#check list length and act accordingly
if len(images) >= 3:
    for image in images:
        image.click()
```

Comment: Thank you - this works for 1 particular image. If I wanted to search for more than one image would I just copy the code x times or am I making it harder than it needs to be?

Comment: I've encountered just one problem. When set at >=2, it will only select 2 even if there is 3,4,5 or 6 additional images.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean exactly when you say "more than one image"? If you meant performing the same procedure for other images then you can define this piece of code as a function and reuse it with different arguments, say image name and number of images on screen that you expect to see. You will then have to call this function for each specific image separately.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Do you mean it does not work with different images?